# Can an n-parallelotope be multiplied and added like a three-dimensional paralleliped concerning volume?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

Suppose we have a list of vectors $a_1, a_2, ..., a_n \in \mathbb{R}^n$ that define an n-parallelotope $p_n$ (understood as the n-dimensional generalization of a paralleliped or parallelogram). Let's denote by $Vol(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$ the hyper-volume of $p_n$ (which is understood as the length, area and volume for the special cases where $n=1, n=2$ and $n=3$, respectively). If we now look at the simple case where $n=2$, we have two vectors $a_1$ and $a_2$ that define a parallelogram $p_2$. It is clear that $p_2$ has the following two properties:

1. $Vol(c\cdot a_1,a_2)=Vol(a_1,c\cdot a_2)=c\cdot Vol(a_1,a_2)$ for some constant $c\in \mathbb{R}$.
2. $Vol(a_1,v+w)=Vol(a_1,v)+Vol(a_1,w)$ for some vectors $v,w \in \mathbb{R}^2$ (this property could perhaps be called [Cavalieri's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavalieri%27s_principle)):

If we now look at the case where $n=3$ it is still possible to visualize why both properties should be true. In this case, three vectors would define a paralleliped $p_3$. But do these properties also hold for the case where $n>3$? That is, do properties 1 and 2 also hold for the case where $n>3$ such that four or more vectors define a hyper-paralleliped? For the case where $n\leq 3$ both properties can be easily verified by appealing to visual intuition, but for more than three dimensions I do not have any idea why both properties could be true (if they are).

Comment: Yes, they hold. Since both properties fixes $n-1$ vectors, you can visualize their hyperplane as a plane which stays untouched.

Comment: @Berci thanks. Do you have a hint where I could learn more about the why part of my question? I completed introductory courses in calculus and linear algebra, so my knowledge is quite basic.

Comment: I'd suggest to look up *determinant*, as it's just that. A special case of *multilinear forms*.